# Coexisting routing beetween Angular 4 and angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an angular 4 / angularJS project (it's being upgraded).

I encounter a problem with the routing.

I am using AngularJS router at the moment :

I have 2 route

```
 { path: '/items/:items/list/ajs', name: 'AngularJSComponent', component: 'angularJSComponent' },
 { path: '/items/:items/list/aj4', name: 'DowngradeAngular4Component', component: 'downgradeAngular4Component'}
```

My downgradeAngular4Component is totally empty :

Component =>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

declare const angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'angular4Component',
    templateUrl: './angular4Component.component.html',
    providers: []
})
export class Angular4Component implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}
}

angular.module('downgradeComponent').directive('downgradeAngular4Component', downgradeComponent({ component: Angular4Component }));
```

TEMPLATE =>

```
<div>HELLO WORLD</div>
```

When I call this component from angularJS using 
`$location.path("/items/itemID/list/aj4");`

I do call my component, it display correctly the `Hello World`

But from that point, no matter which URL i put in the app or any `$location.path` change from any `AngularJS` Component nothing happen, the navbar url change but the ng-outlet is freezed with the ng4 component.

[image]

**EDIT :** THIS is the console in chrome, this doesn't move no matter where i go.

[image]